# Why does the bitcoin wiki have an invalid ssl certificate and show PHP errors at the top of every page?

Tags: bitcoin-wiki

I figured this would be cleaned up pretty quickly, but it seems to have been that way for a month or more.  Was just curious - it is many people's first exposure to bitcoin and doesn't really install confidence.

Comment: Looks fine here.

Comment: Also, poor fit for Stackexchange. The question should either be directed to Mark Karpeles or one of the admins (https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?title=Special:ListUsers&group=sysop), or put up on the forum for wider discussion.

Comment: I think operating the wiki would be a good candidate for the Bitcoin Foundation to take on

Comment: http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=118465.0  http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=123448.0  https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=123293.0

Comment: I got only warnings no errors I use Android 2.3's default browser - anonymous a lot, registered only one ~~~~ Klaas V